# Dismiss view controller doesn't deallocate memory

Tags: cocoa, memory-management, memory-leaks, xamarin.mac

I have several modals in my application , here is extentions method what I use for every of them:

```
public static void CloseAndDismissViewController (this NSViewController vc)
        {
            vc.View.Window.Close ();    
            vc.DismissController (vc);
            vc.RemoveFromParentViewController ();
        }
```

But I doesn't deallocate memory, here is screen shot from profiler :

[image]

finally , such cases cause application crashes....

I'm using PrepareForSegue method to pass data from source to destination vc, like this one :

```
public override void PrepareForSegue (NSStoryboardSegue segue, NSObject sender)
        {
if (segue.Identifier.Equals ("ImageInfo")) {
                var vc = segue.DestinationController as InfoViewController;
                vc.SetData (item);

            } 
}
```

Comment: How are you creating the viewcontroller, and how are you showing the view?

Comment: I'm using segue

Comment: Hmm, I don't use storyboards or segues so I'm not familiar with that. Is there any C# code involved in creating or showing the viewcontroller?

Comment: You can just pass data from source to destination, I use PrepareForSegue method, like this one : 
if (segue.Identifier.Equals ("ImageInfo")) {
var vc = segue.DestinationController as InfoViewController;
    vc.SetData (item);}

Comment: I have updated question

Comment: Is there anything in SetData that could cause it not being cleaned up (like subscribing to events)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127713/discussion-between-svn-and-nininea).